# Unhandled Exception in 2.5.0

Tags: arangodb

After unloading two collections, ArangoDB 2.5.0 terminated with exception:

```
2015-03-20T14:59:58Z [9436] ERROR Unhandled exception: -1073741819
```

will crash now.

Does anybody know what went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Update 2015-05-18: verbose-log-mode shows this:

```
2015-05-18T07:10:50Z [1724] ERROR encountered out-of-memory error
2015-05-18T07:10:50Z [1724] ERROR JavaScript exception in file 'd:/Program Files
/ArangoDB/ArangoDB 2.5.3/share/arangodb/js/server/modules/org/arangodb/arango-st
atement.js' at 86,45: [ArangoError 3: out of memory (while executing)]
2015-05-18T07:10:50Z [1724] ERROR !  var result = AQL_EXECUTE(this._query, this.
_bindVars, opts);
2015-05-18T07:10:50Z [1724] ERROR !                                            ^

2015-05-18T07:10:50Z [1724] ERROR stacktrace: Error: out of memory (while execut
ing)\n  at Error (native)\n  at ArangoStatement.execute (d:/Program Files/Arango
DB/ArangoDB 2.5.3/share/arangodb/js/server/modules/org/arangodb/arango-statement
.js:86:45)\n  at d:/Program Files/ArangoDB/ArangoDB 2.5.3/share/arangodb/js/serv
er/modules/org/arangodb/foxx/queues/manager.js:66:12\n  at Array.forEach (native
)\n  at db._executeTransaction.action (d:/Program Files/ArangoDB/ArangoDB 2.5.3/
share/arangodb/js/server/modules/org/arangodb/foxx/queues/manager.js:43:34)\n  a
t [object ArangoDatabase].ArangoDatabase._executeTransaction (d:/Program Files/A
rangoDB/ArangoDB 2.5.3/share/arangodb/js/server/modules/org/arangodb/arango-data
base.js:142:10)\n  at Object.exports.manage (d:/Program Files/ArangoDB/ArangoDB
2.5.3/share/arangodb/js/server/modules/org/arangodb/foxx/queues/manager.js:37:6)
\n  at eval (<anonymous>:2:51)\n  at eval (<anonymous>:3:7)\n  at eval (<anonymo
us>:3:19)\n


#
# Fatal error in ..\..\src\heap\mark-compact.cc, line 2137
# CHECK(success) failed
#
2015-05-18T07:10:52Z [1724] ERROR Unhandled exception: -1073741819 - will crash
now.
```

Comment: 2015-05-12T20:34:04Z [7780] INFO In database '_system': Database is up-to-date (20503/prod/standalone/existing)
2015-05-12T20:34:04Z [7780] INFO In database 'SIOS': Database is up-to-date (20503/prod/standalone/existing)
2015-05-12T20:34:04Z [7780] INFO In database 'UniRelations': Database is up-to-date (20503/prod/standalone/existing)
2015-05-12T20:34:04Z [7780] INFO Authentication is turned off
2015-05-12T20:34:04Z [7780] INFO ArangoDB (version 2.5.3 [win64]) is ready for business. Have fun!
2015-05-13T07:26:12Z [7780] ERROR Unhandled exception: -1073741819 - will crash now.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it doesn't appear here on our AMD64 Windows Server 2012 R2.

Can you install procdump (https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/operations/installation/compiling/compile-on-windows/)
so we can get a little more information?

```
procdump -accepteula -e -ma <process ID of the arangod> c:\tmp\core.dmp
```

(the process id is in your logfile in the brackets, it would have been 9436 in your incident above)

Procdump will catch this exception, and write a dump file.

Comment: I try my best. But procdump can't find the process-id anymore, as arangod is crashed. BY THE WAY, that happend in Arango2.5.1 again:
2015-03-23T13:57:41Z [1668] ERROR Unhandled exception: -1073741819 - will crash now.
D:\Program Files\ArangoDB\ArangoDB 2.5.1\bin>

Comment: you need to start the arangodb daemon, then attach procdump to it, then do your tests. A more detailed description on howto reproduce it would be nice ;-)

Comment: It took a long time until I could produce core dumps again. But now I have one. zipped, it has more than 2 GB. Now, how could I hand this over to you?

Comment: First - can we have a look at the logfile? whats the last nod before death? Second - yes really sounds like a challenge...

Comment: Here the next crash. It happened after a pause of work, when I clicked into the Browser in order to refresh the query. Hm, yes, this one could become tricky :-) I've appened the log tail to the description above.

Comment: can you try to get the backtrace using windbg? https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/How_to_get_a_backtrace_with_WinDbg? Whats the last lines before the unhandled exception?

Comment: Eventually arangod wrote a minidump file, which shouldn't be that huge; can you have a look at files with minidump_* in your temporary path?

Comment: Couldn't find a minidump yet. But verbose-log mode has printed out something. I added its output to the main description of the question above. Does this help?

Comment: In addition to that, I sometimes observe following log output which NOT leads to a crash ... the system still seems to work fine afterwards: 2015-05-18T09:52:39Z [10220] DEBUG [C:\cygwin64\home\jenkins\ArangoDB-2.5.3\lib\
.\GeneralServer/GeneralServerDispatcher.h:416] shutdownHandler called, but no ha
ndler is known for task

Comment: You may get the later in case of interrupted tcp connections.

Comment: Thanks. Then the later one is separated fom the origin problem. It again happend, that during query as well as after some idle time (minutes, even hours) the server crashes. My bet would be something in the area of garbage-collect. Unfortunately I still couldn't solve that dump-stuff on my side .... I keep on trying.